# combining the results of pettitte test in columns

Tags: r

my data look like this. i have the data on groundwater level for some wells over the time. I did pettitt test to detect the change point in that. now I want to combine the results of pettitt test for all each well in columns. how can I do that?

```
WLCODE   year.   pomrb
W04790  2018    14.99
W04824  2018    8.05
W04791  2018    10.85
W04299  2018    8.87
W04797  2018    4.3
W04039  2018    7.25
W04799  2018    5.58
W04300  2018    14.35
W04790  2017    14.99
W04824  2017    7.9
W04791  2017    9.6
W04295  2017    8.24
W04302  2017    2.6
W04300  2017    0.63
W32596  2016    5.69
W32607  2016    2.15
W32602  2016    10.9
W32605  2016    12.47
W32612  2016    10.65
W32635  2016    3.78
W32490  2016    9.95
W32491  2016    4.03
W32485  2016    5.6
W32505  2016    3.13
W31146  2016    3.9
W32537  2016    7.46
W32530  2016    2.41
W32540  2016    6.35
W32545  2016    5
W32549  2016    5.3
W32547  2016    5.26
W32554  2016    6.79
W32557  2016    7.97
W32572  2016    8.2
W32575  2016    9.03
W32577  2016    9.8
W04299  2016    8.87
W04797  2016    4.34
W04799  2016    5.6
W25598  2016    7.36
W25612  2016    8.8
W04809  2015    4.86
W04826  2015    3.73
W04792  2015    13.15
W04798  2015    9.54
W04034  2015    14.51
W04793  2015    9.25
W03834  2015    4.62
W04808  2015    12.42
W04043  2015    7.68
W04795  2015    12.34
W04037  2015    12.22
W04822  2015    10.72
W04821  2015    6.53
W04807  2015    7.95
W04295  2015    8.24
W04299  2015    8.87
W04797  2015    3.69
W25404  2014    3.93
W25438  2014    7.18
W25451  2014    5.56
W25476  2014    4.37
W25293  2014    5.06
W04809  2014    4.07
W04792  2014    10.45
W04798  2014    9.35
W04034  2014    14.51
W04809  2013    4.3
W04043  2013    6.8
W04795  2013    11.82
W04822  2013    11.7
W04821  2013    4.5
W04819  2013    4.26
W04042  2013    12.7
W04798  2012    11.5
W04034  2012    11.45
W03834  2012    5.59
W04808  2012    12.32
W04043  2012    9
W04795  2012    12.67
W04822  2012    11.8
W04821  2012    8.3
W04807  2012    4.35
W04806  2012    7.9
W04287  2012    9
W04288  2012    5.75
W03836  2012    4.13
W03835  2012    6.6
W04809  2011    4.04
W04822  2011    10.7
W04821  2011    7.26
W04807  2011    3.04
W04806  2011    5.51
W04287  2011    7.82
W04288  2011    4.15
W03836  2011    3.38
W04801  2011    4.4
W04298  2011    7.51
W04302  2011    2.89
W04300  2011    1.21
W04809  2010    4.6
W04792  2010    12.38
W04822  2010    11.57
W04821  2010    4.27
W04807  2010    5.47
W04806  2010    8.44
W04287  2010    8.14
W03833  2010    3.73
W04797  2009    3.6
W03834  2009    4.29
W04799  2009    4.8
W04281  2009    6.6
W04790  2009    10.05
W04824  2009    4.88
W04791  2009    8.52
W04295  2009    7.04
W04299  2009    6.57
W04300  2009    1.85
W04296  2009    5.66
W04816  2009    4.06
W04303  2009    11.97
W04797  2008    3.15
W04790  2008    7.77
W04824  2008    5.96
W04791  2008    7.92
W04295  2008    6.84
W04299  2008    6.94
W04300  2008    2.5
W04296  2008    5.6
W04816  2008    3.81
W04303  2008    13.5
W03914  2008    9.9
W04281  2008    5.9
W03833  2008    3.46
W04040  2008    2.18
W04283  2008    16.83
W04806  2008    7.2
W04287  2008    7.82
W04288  2008    4.64
W03836  2008    3.31
W04039  2008    7.12
W04797  2007    4.55
W03834  2007    4.21
W04799  2007    7.35
W04790  2007    12.65
W04824  2007    5.95
W04791  2007    8.9
W04295  2007    6.96
W04299  2007    7.64
W03914  2007    9.18
W04281  2007    8.25
W04286  2007    7.32
W04040  2007    2.53
W04283  2007    16.8
W04801  2007    2.1
W04298  2007    7.76
W04299  2006    6.24
W04300  2006    3.25
W04296  2006    4.65
W04816  2006    6.33
W04818  2006    3.4
W04303  2006    13.31
W03914  2006    8.15
W04281  2006    6.45
W04286  2006    5.7
W04040  2006    1.78
W04283  2006    16.45
W04801  2006    2.55
W04298  2006    6.51
W04302  2006    2.25
W03835  2006    8.4
W04293  2006    2.65
W04819  2006    5.24
W04042  2006    9.66
W04290  2006    9.58
W04789  2006    6.3
W04806  2006    7
W04287  2006    7.4
W04288  2006    4.35
W03836  2006    3.3
W04811  2006    4.68
W04043  2006    7.5
W04795  2006    11.92
W04037  2006    11.63
W04822  2006    9.6
W04821  2006    3.8
W04807  2006    4.33
W04821  2005    4.06
W04807  2005    8.35
W04809  2005    5.27
W04820  2005    5.95
W04792  2005    9.85
W04798  2005    9.75
W04034  2005    10.05
W03834  2005    3.34
W04038  2005    8.71
W04796  2004    7.5
W04808  2004    9.52
W04799  2004    5.2
W04790  2004    9.9
W04823  2004    5.28
W04824  2004    4.4
W04791  2004    8.84
W04295  2004    6.89
W04299  2004    8.87
W04797  2004    3.53
W04301  2004    9.9
W04296  2004    8.7
W04816  2004    4.95
W04818  2004    12.5
W04303  2004    15.47
W03914  2004    9.58
W04281  2004    6.52
W04286  2004    5.95
W04040  2004    3.33
W04283  2004    17.1
W04801  2004    6.28
W04298  2004    7.19
W04302  2004    3.66
W04300  2004    5.75
W04293  2004    7.58
W04042  2004    14.77
W04035  2004    8.68
W04290  2004    9.84
W04789  2004    8.8
W03833  2004    4.69
W04806  2004    9.45
W04287  2004    8.7
W04288  2004    5.13
W03836  2004    4.93
W04815  2004    10.75
W04811  2004    7.96
W04810  2004    8.52
W04037  2003    24.9
W04822  2003    12.37
W04821  2003    3.47
W04807  2003    8.51
W04809  2003    6.84
W04039  2002    8.4
W04799  2002    5.5
W04790  2002    10.36
W04823  2002    4.42
W04824  2002    8.51
W04791  2002    8.3
W04295  2002    6.89
W04299  2002    8.87
W04797  2002    3.4
W04301  2002    9.9
W04816  2002    7.47
W04818  2002    10.32
W04303  2002    15.25
W03914  2002    10.48
W04789  2002    8.72
W03833  2002    6.05
W04806  2002    9.93
W04287  2002    11.35
W04288  2002    5.65
W04815  2002    4.25
W04811  2002    5.54
W04810  2002    10.51
W04038  2002    7.21
W04796  2001    5.9
W04793  2001    9.6
W04039  2001    7.5
W04799  2001    4.7
W04790  2001    11.2
W04823  2001    8.06
W04791  2001    7.7
W04295  2001    7.07
W04299  2001    8.87
W04797  2001    1.65
W04301  2001    9.9
W04818  2001    5.35
W03914  2001    9.28
W04281  2001    7.1
W04286  2001    6.66
W04040  2001    2.63
W04283  2001    12.7
W04298  2001    7.41
W04302  2001    4.18
W04300  2001    2.85
W04819  2001    5.09
W04805  2001    9.7
W04042  2001    8.25
W04035  2001    9.98
W04290  2001    9.84
W04789  2001    7.15
W04806  2001    8.58
W04287  2001    9.45
W04288  2001    5.62
W04815  2001    2.55
W04811  2001    5.84
W04810  2001    9.96
W03835  2001    9.4
W04043  2001    9.9
W04795  2001    9.62
W04037  2001    15.88
W04822  2001    12.2
W04038  2001    6.81
W04796  2000    7.25
W04793  2000    9.52
W04039  2000    6.03
W04799  2000    4.66
W04041  2000    2.77
W04790  2000    7.77
W04823  2000    6.26
W04791  2000    7.9
W04295  2000    6.24
W04299  2000    8.36
W04797  2000    1.58
W04816  2000    4.28
W04818  2000    7.75
W04303  2000    14.95
W03914  2000    8.72
W04281  2000    7.88
W04040  2000    5.78
W04283  2000    15.72
W04805  2000    8.02
W03914  1999    10.81
W04281  1999    8.6
W04790  1999    13.19
W04823  1999    4.22
W04791  1999    8.19
W04295  1999    7.33
W04299  1999    8.88
W04797  1999    4.2
W04796  1999    8.3
W04038  1999    7.42
W04039  1999    7.8
W04799  1999    5.49
W04811  1999    6.08
W04810  1999    7.63
W03835  1999    8.87
W04819  1999    4.63
W04805  1999    8.39
W04035  1999    7.36
W04789  1999    6.91
W03833  1999    6.91
W04040  1999    2.85
W04298  1999    5.17
W04302  1999    3.58
W04043  1999    8.7
W04795  1999    12.91
W04822  1999    11.53
W04821  1999    3.63
W04807  1999    6.3
W04806  1999    8.88
W04288  1999    5.7
W04815  1999    2.45
W04299  1998    3.13
W04797  1998    2.59
W04810  1998    7.4
W04819  1998    3.81
W04805  1998    7.9
W04035  1998    9.07
W04789  1998    9.01
W03833  1998    5.72
W04799  1997    5.54
W04041  1997    4.57
W04811  1997    5.08
W04810  1997    6.16
W03835  1997    7.56
W04819  1997    4.85
W04805  1997    7.9
W04043  1997    9.22
W04795  1997    13.3
W04822  1997    11.98
W04821  1997    7.86
W04807  1997    5.6
W03832  1997    10.26
W04806  1997    8.57
W04288  1997    5.42
W04297  1997    6.91
W03914  1996    11.12
W04815  1996    6.42
W04797  1996    2.86
W04796  1996    7.42
W04038  1996    6.74
W04039  1996    7.05
W04799  1996    5.04
W04041  1996    8.77
W04811  1996    4.94
W04810  1996    6.6
W03835  1996    9.48
W04819  1996    5.13
W04805  1996    8.17
W04035  1996    9.21
W04789  1996    5.33
W04795  1996    12.81
```

```
CIT_pomrb <-read.csv("/Users/priyankaupreti/Desktop/CIT_pomrb.csv")
sp <- split(CIT_pomrb, CIT_pomrb$WLCODE)
results_pt <- lapply(sp, function(CIT_pomrb){
  tryCatch(pettitt.test(CIT_pomrb[, 3]),
           error = function(e) e)
})
```

I am getting the output like this-

```
$W08371

    Pettitt's test for single change-point detection

data:  CIT_pomrb[, 3]
U* = 37, p-value = 0.1224
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
probable change point at time K 
                              7 


$W08372

    Pettitt's test for single change-point detection

data:  CIT_pomrb[, 3]
U* = 36, p-value = 0.142
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
probable change point at time K 
                              8
```

I want to produce a table using this output and export it to excel with WLCODE in each row and statistic, p-value, and probable change point at time K in columns. How can I do that? Please help.

Comment: How do you want to plot it?

Comment: how  can I combine its output in columns, including p value and the probable change point at time K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output from `pettitt.test()` is a list, making `results_pt` a list of lists. While it's often fairly straight forward to extract elements from a nested list like this, using `sapply()` and the extract functions

```
library(trend)

# to see what name each element has
str(results_pt[[1]])
# List of 8
#  $ nobs       : int 1
#  $ statistic  : Named num 0
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "U*"
#  $ estimate   : Named int 1
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "probable change point at time K"
#  $ p.value    : num 2
#  $ data.name  : chr "CIT_pomrb[, 3]"
#  $ alternative: chr "two.sided"
#  $ data       : num 0
#   ..- attr(*, "nm")= chr "Uk"
#  $ method     : chr "Pettitt's test for single change-point detection"
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "htest" "cptest"

ex1 <- sapply(results_pt, "[[", "p.value")
ex1[1:3]
#    W03832    W03833    W03834 
# 2.0000000 0.2907114 0.4738555 

ex2 <- sapply(results_pt, "[", c("nobs", "p.value"))
ex2[,1:3]
#         W03832 W03833    W03834   
# nobs    1      6         5        
# p.value 2      0.2907114 0.4738555
```

the lists `pettitt.test()` produces appear to be not quite consistent, making things a bit more difficult. In this case It might be better to modify the `lapply()` call you have to reformat the output

```
pt.l <- lapply(sp, function(x) {
    pt <- pettitt.test(x[,3])
    with(pt, data.frame(code=x[1,1], nobs, statistic, estimate, p.value)[1,])
})

pt.df <- do.call(rbind, pt.l)
rownames(pt.df) <- NULL
head(pt.df)
#     code nobs statistic estimate   p.value
# 1 W03832    1         0        1 2.0000000
# 2 W03833    6         9        3 0.2907114
# 3 W03834    5         6        2 0.4738555
# 4 W03835    6         6        2 0.8487457
# 5 W03836    5         4        4 1.0545848
# 6 W03914    9        14        7 0.4682726
```

This will give a few warnings, but they are inconsequential.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was really very useful. :-)

Comment: @priyankaupreti: Good to hear. You might also [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.

Comment: oh okay, sure :-)